# Forge 2D viewer arc measure

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

why doesn't it snap to the ends of the arcs (dwg file).

File: https://easyupload.io/jl5gp4

[image: snap inner arc]

[image: no snap on end of arc]

Comment: are you able to share a sample DWG model?

Comment: yes, I can send it by email